# How to convert calculator operation element to a string to get the solution and then return the solution back into the element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, calculator

So I'm making a JQuery calculator in codepen and I'm basically having the buttons write out the equation. So far so good. However I run into some problems once I try to get back the result of the calculations. How do I convert the calculations element in HTML into a variable string in JQuery and then return it back into the HTML as the solution?
Here is my codepen project link, as well as the problematic section of code: http://codepen.io/Starkiller12/pen/eJYGXY

```
 $("#equal").click(function() {
   var x = $("p");
    $("p").empty();
   $("p").html(x);
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like following:

```
$("#equal").click(function() {
    var arr = $('p').text().split('+');
    var first=parseInt(arr[0]);
    var two=parseInt(arr[1]);
    $("p").empty();
    $("p").html(first + two);
  })
```

Here it is done for addition(+).
You can do same for other.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ek8a83e6/)**

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it up. I'm kind of confused though. What does parseInt do exactly?

Comment: @majestyc54 `parseInt()` will convert string to integer (so if you measure the `height()` of an element that reads '16px' your result is 16 as an integer (lack of single comments is on purpose here))  [see link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Answer (score 0):

your variable is storing the jquery object, not its contents

so `var x = $("p");` should be `var x = $("p").text();` or `var x = $("p").html();`

Comment: While I can see the logic of what you say, doing what you recommended didn't work and the equals button still remained unresponsive.

Comment: The answer below should get you going—if you are adding your operators like '+' and '-' to a string you will need to split the string and perform the actual math, and then spit out the result.

Comment: Ah. Now I'm starting to get it. I wasn't aware that I needed to split it. The more you know. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No prob! So yes, your other answer there will work for '+', but I'm sure you can see how to setup the rest... you can get creative with maybe some regex to find your operators or look for them in an array...